# migrate data from one server to another while keeping few tables data unchanged basically exclude few tables while using pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, data-migration, pg-dump, pg-restore

Lets say my database have 4 tables A,B,C and D..Now I want while restoring data of table A and B remains unchanged and data of C and D should changed.
I am using below command to restore the dump.
`pg_restore --verbose  --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -d db_name latest.dump`
command for taking dump
`pg_dump -Fc database_name > ~/Downloads/latest-stage.dump`

here I am using clean flag because If I dont use it then It will generate error related to indexing and key constraints.

NOTE : **Basically I am moving my data from one server to another server but I want data of few table should not change.**

Answer (score 0):

Your restore command is restoring the whole database. Depending on how the dump was created you can restore specific tables.

Depending on how your dump was taking you can use restore specific tables.

[pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html)

[pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html)

I would create a dump from the original db using the `format` method. If thats not possible, its usually done to restore the table elsewhere and copy the data across either with a db link or foreign server, depending on your set up.

Comment: If I exclude some tables during dumping process but still when I restore all my db is cleared and data is lost and if I dont clear db I gets alot of error relted to key constraints and indexing..

Comment: You need to include the original dump command. It looks like you are restoring an entire Db. Read the docs there are ways around this.